# Unable to externalize Hikari properties with Spring Cloud Config in Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud, hikaricp, spring-cloud-config

I have this property file which I store in a GitHub repo:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=*DB URL*
spring.datasource.username=*USERNAME*
spring.datasource.password=*ENCRYPTED PASSWORD*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

My config server pulls up the details from this repo.

Now I have a client that requires these properties to configure the HikariDataSource.

but when I start the client I get the following Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database url for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Seems to me like Hikari is unable to get these properties at start-up.

I was configuring my Hikari DataSource like so in my config class:

```
@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
```

After removing this bean I still get the same error.

Any idea about what I should be doing here?

Thanks.

Comment: If you put those properties locally without config server does it work?

Comment: I'm sorry, you store the password in a GitHub repo? And you post the password on StackOverflow?? What???

Comment: I want to externalize those properties using spring cloud.

Also the password I have posted is encrypted...I'm still  going to remove them now, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Externalizing the properties in a git repo is part of the spring cloud config setup.

My password will always remain encrypted.

Comment: Do you see logs that you actually connect to the config server?  can you show your bootstrap.properties?

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) to the main class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to the main class.